# Import android studio Google map project

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, import

I am working with a friend on a project and therefore needs to import it to my computer.
But this project contains a Google Map Activity. Therefore, when I try to run it on a mobile, it opens perfectly (I can use the login activity) but the map stays blank (The google map application works fine so it is not a connectivity problem).
Our application works however fine when we run it from my friend's computer (where it was created).
I think the problem comes from the "Google Maps API key".

```
<resources>
<!--
TODO: Before you run your application, you need a Google Maps API key.

To get one, follow this link, follow the directions and press "Create" at the end: https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=XXXX

You can also add your credentials to an existing key, using this line:
XXXXXXXX

Once you have your key (it starts with "AIza"), replace the "google_maps_key"
string in this file.
-->
<string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
    Key
</string>
```

But when I try to create a new one, it doesn't change anything. I think that it comes from the fact that the link remains the same.

My questions are therefore : 
Is it possible to have the same application with the same "Google Maps API key" on two different computers? 
And if not is it possible to change the link provided by Android Studio to be able to create a new key that will work with the project ?
Or do I need to recreate completely the project each time ?

Comment: You're probably using a debug certificate to generate your key. Make sure you use a release certificate (see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key)). That or you're using a debug keystore file, in which case, you should create your own.

Answer (score 0):

I litreally had the same problem with my friend as well.
What happens is that when he made a new Map api key, he gave his credentials for it, so now only he can run the project in his PC(you can copy the apk built by his system and that will work fine on your phone).

---

What you should do is get a new api key and give credentials of both your systems. This way you both can work on the project. To  get your credentials type the following in cmd prompt

---

`keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

---

Here is a link you can check
[here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup#release-cert)